# Google Translate: TranslateElement is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-translate

i was trying adding Google translate dropdown to a website.
For the sake of simplicity, i added all the code in the same place of the page.
I have added this code (slightly beautified):

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement(
    {
      pageLanguage: 'it',
      includedLanguages: 'de,en,es,fr,it',
      gaTrack: true,
      gaId: 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X'
    },
    'google_translate_element'
  );
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

On the Chrome console i receive this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: google.translate.TranslateElement is not a function

This error code doesn't show up with a google search, and i don't know what caused it.

Any help is really appreciated...
Thanks!

Comment: Your code worked fine for me in this plunker... http://plnkr.co/edit/UiIxrHc9GU5KgcLIPxSd?p=preview

Comment: yes, even in my live website the translate bar appears, but the webdeveloper console gave me an error of Uncaught exception.  Anyway, the solution proposed by Carlos2W solved this error.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add google script before your own.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement(
    {
      pageLanguage: 'it',
      includedLanguages: 'de,en,es,fr,it',
      gaTrack: true,
      gaId: 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X'
    },
    'google_translate_element'
  );
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, it's too late, maybe i need to sleep...  
Carlos, this worked flawlessy, i don't know why google gave the code with the external script after the inline script (and i don't know why i didn't tried this before).  
Thank you very much!

Comment: This actually isn't the correct answer. The Google page itself suggests placing the google script after that function definition, and there's a reason for that: the script will attempt calling the `googleTranslateElementInit()` function you've defined earlier. You will not get a `ReferenceError` until that function is called.